# EC2 instances go missing when shutdown

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am facing a strange issue in which I lose the instance when I shut it down. I launched publicly available ami-ccb35ea5 for Centos and after running it for couple of hours I bought it down but issuing shutdown –h now command.

In the AWS Web Console, the instance went to terminated state and after few hours I was not even able to see it.

Not sure why the instances are getting disappeared.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_the_difference_between_using_the_local_instance_store_and_Amazon_Elastic_Block_storage_for_the_root_device

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the Instance Initiated Shutdown Behavior**

By default, when you initiate a shutdown from an Amazon EBS-backed instance (using a command such as **shutdown**, **halt**, or **poweroff**), the instance stops. You can change this behavior using the *InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior* attribute for the instance so that it terminates instead. You can update this attribute while the instance is running or stopped.

You can update the *InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior* attribute using the Amazon EC2 console or the command line. The *InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior* attribute only applies when you perform a shutdown from the operating system of the instance itself; it does not apply when you stop an instance using the *StopInstances* API or the Amazon EC2 console.

To change the shutdown behavior of an instance using the console

> 1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Instances.
> 3. Select the instance, select **Actions**, **Instance Settings**, and then choose **Change Shutdown Behavior**. The current behavior is
>      already selected.
> 4. To change the behavior, select an option from the **Shutdown behavior** list, and then select **Apply**.

[image: Shutdown behaviour]

[AWS Doc reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html)